# UnstructuredURLLoader/SeleniumURLLoader not working in LangChain for JS based websites

Tags: selenium-webdriver, langchain, py-langchain

I try to use document loader for websites urls. However for `UnstructuredURLLoader` some websites return:

```
(Document(page_content='Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker',
 metadata={'source': 'https://wellfound.com/company/chorus-one'})
```

So I wanted to use `SeleniumURLLoader` that is [advertised in the doc to overcome](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_loaders/integrations/url) the issues.

However, after installing `pip install selenium webdriver_manager`.

```
 selenium                      4.10.0
 webdriver-manager             3.8.6
```

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredURLLoader, SeleniumURLLoader

loaders = SeleniumURLLoader(urls=urls)
data = loaders.load()
```

I keep getting errors:

> The version of chrome cannot be detected. Trying with latest driver version

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
> Stacktrace:
> #0 0x55c7d5ee44e3 
> #1 0x55c7d5c13c76 
> #2 0x55c7d5c3a757 
> #3 0x55c7d5c39029 
> #4 0x55c7d5c77ccc 
> #5 0x55c7d5c7747f 
> #6 0x55c7d5c6ede3 
> #7 0x55c7d5c442dd 
> #8 0x55c7d5c4534e 
> #9 0x55c7d5ea43e4 
> #10 0x55c7d5ea83d7 
> #11 0x55c7d5eb2b20 
> #12 0x55c7d5ea9023 
> #13 0x55c7d5e771aa 
> #14 0x55c7d5ecd6b8 
> #15 0x55c7d5ecd847 
> #16 0x55c7d5edd243 
> #17 0x7fbddad0d609 start_thread

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should verify whether your URLs are directed towards any of the following non-HTML file types: `jpg`, `jpeg`, `JPG`, `JPEG`, `png`, `PNG`, `svg`, `gif`, `GIF`, `ttf`, `woff`, `js`, `json`, `css`, `css2`, `ico`, `xml`, `mp3`, `mp4`, `php`, `rdf`, `axd`, `eot`, `pdf`, `doc`, `docx`, `xlsx`. If that is indeed the case, you must eliminate such URLs, as these files cannot be processed using either `UnstructuredURLLoader` or `SeleniumURLLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install chromium
sudo apt-get install chromium

Comment: @Jason Then how to properly install chromium in this situation?

Comment: @mCs which OS are you working on?

Comment: I use MacOs but I do have the Chromium browser installed.